# Reducing unused space/arrow length for cytoscape js layouts

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using the cytoscape js library for displaying a hierarchy of images. I followed the example on http://jsbin.com/gist/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5?js,output and found that the breadthfirst layout is what I need.

However, I find the rendered result unsatisfactory due to too much unused space. The arrows are too long. Even the example (http://jsbin.com/gist/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5?js,output) has this issue. For this example, I tried the following

1. Increase the "height/width" in `.selector('node') .css({`
2. Muck around with the `distanceX` and `distanceY` (node spacing) variables in `layout.breadthfirst.js` (line 352).

I am unable to reduce the unused space or reduce the length of the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Ticket to follow: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/737

If you want a new feature in future, please [file a ticket](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

For rushing Devs, try this layout option:

```
spacingFactor: 0
```

The manual says :

```
spacingFactor: 1.75, // positive spacing factor, 
                     // larger => more space between nodes (N.B. n/a if causes overlap)
```

That's the result of the ticket https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/737 reported by maxkfranz.